# Check particular Extension File and Get its Name C#

Tags: c#

I want check particular Extension File is available by giving Path to the File.
For Example: C:\Example have Example.txt, Sample.pdf, Sample.docx

By Giving the Folder path I want to check particular extension[.pdf] File is Available if there get the file name [Sample].

```
                var directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
                FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
```

Getting all File.But i don't want to loop through and find its extension. Any solution

Comment: You will need to loop in some manner. You could also use Linq for that. Make use of Where(fileInfo => fileInfo.Name.EndsWith(...)) or something like that

Comment: `GetFiles()` has an overload that accepts a search pattern. You could do `Directroy.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.pdf");` and then check the result is not empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all files with the extension only without using loop but of course you will need to use something else like LINQ. This will retrieve all your files extensions names including duplicate ones:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\ComputerName\\Documents");
var files = directory.GetFiles().Select(c => c.Extension);
```

To check if any specific extension exist:

```
//Check if the extension exists:
 var boolFiles = directory.GetFiles().Any(c => c.Extension == ".pdf");
```

To get only the name of files based on your extension:

```
var getFilesBasedOnExtension = directory.GetFiles()
                .Where(c => c.Extension == ".pdf").Select(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: Any is available on IEnumerable, including arrays, so GetFiles() can immediately use .Any(), no need to convert it to .ToList() first.